# Access a function's property inside the function

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to assign a property to a function inside the function itself. I do not want to assign it to the object of invocation. So I want the equivalent of doing this:

```
var test  = function() {                    
    return true;         
};

test.a = 'property on a function';
alert(test.a);
```

Instead of this, where the property is assigned to a global object:

```
var testAgain = function() {
   this.a = "this property won't be assigned to the function";

   return true;  
};

testAgain();
alert(window.a);
```

Edit: To clarify, I'm wondering if there's something like this:

```
var test = function() {
   function.a = 'property on a function';
};
alert(test.a); // returns 'property on a function'
```

Without knowing that the function is called test or having to execute it. 
I know of course this isn't valid syntax

Comment: Please try to explain, i don't see what you are trying to do

Comment: Are you calling the function, or using the `new` keyword on it?

Comment: The only way for a function to get to itself (without knowing its own name) is via the deprecated `arguments.callee` - that's going to stop working someday too (and it may already not work in "strict" mode).

Comment: That said: why do you want to do this?

Comment: It won't really work this way. Without "new" (or other trickery as Pointy explains), "this" refers to the Window.

Comment: Just set `test.a` inside of `test`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [is there a way to set a property on a function] without knowing that the function is called `test` **or having to execute it**.

Emphasis mine.

You can set a property on a function without knowing what its global variable name is necessarily going to be, however you *do* have to have a reference to the function in one way or another.

The module pattern is as close of a fit as I can think of:

```
window.test = (function () {
    //the function could be named anything...
    function testFn() {
        ...code here...
    }
    //...so long as the same name is used here
    testFn.foo = 'bar';
    return testFn;
}());
window.test.foo; //'bar'
```

The outer closure prevents `testFn` from being accessed anywhere globally, so all other references will have to use `window.test`.

---

<sub>This part of the answer is associated with the prior version of the question.</sub>

The simplest way of doing this is to use a named function:

```
var test = function testFn() {
    testFn.foo = 'bar';
    return true;
};

test.foo; //undefined
test();
test.foo; //'bar'
```

A better way of doing this is to use the module pattern so that you don't accidentally create issues with global leakage:

```
var test = (function () {
    function ret() {
        ret.foo = 'bar';
        return true;
    }
    return ret;
}());

test.foo; //undefined
test();
test.foo; //'bar'
```

Comment: @Rocket, no the function itself didn't have a name, the anonymous function instance was assigned to the `test` variable, which is not the same as having a name. The first code example wont set `window.testFn` (in Chrome, not sure about cross-browser compatibility on this one, which is why I recommend using a closure).

Comment: The whole point is to be able to set a property on the function without needing to know the name of the variable that happens to contain the function.

Comment: And the answer is: you can't.  You need to give the function a name to be able to set a property on it.

Comment: @Rocket, that was never part of the requirements of the question.

Comment: What isn't part of the requirements?

Comment: @Rocket, As per your quote, "And the answer is: you can't. You need to give the function a name to be able to set a property on it." I was saying that there was no requirement preventing a solution where the function was given an explicit name. OP is trying to avoid knowing the name of the ***variable*** that contains the function, which does not preclude the naming of the assigned function.

Comment: Ahh.  I was getting confused between variable names and function names.  I get it now. :-P

Answer (score 1):

```
var testAgain = function() {
    arguments.callee.a = "this property won't be assigned to the function";
    return true;  
};

testAgain();
alert(testAgain.a);​
```

Comment: Should probably avoid using `arguments.callee` now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simple using the name to assign the property like this:

```
var test = function () {
    test.a = 'a';
    return true;
};
```

When `test` is invoked, the property will be set.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/rp33k/)

You *could* use `arguments.callee`, as `su-` said, but that's considered really bad practice. Also, it won't work in strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = function() {
    test.a = 'a';
};
```

Or you can use prototypes, read more [here](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/).